# Error System. component model.win32 exception in source tree

Tags: git, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

I have tried to clone gitlab code by **Atlassian SourceTree*.

The source tree raised a error like that.

[image]

So that I am not able to clone.

How can I resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, try by the git command line in order to see it depends in your credentials issue or in a file system access issue.

Comment: SourceTree sometimes does not use same credentials with git-bash cli (might need putty ppk file for ssh key). Also, your attempt to censor the screenshot is not really working since I can still read them if I zoom the image

Comment: The type of exception (`Win32Exception`) indicates a local error on your machine, nothing with the credentials used for cloning. You have selected "Root" as Local folder. Perhaps if you clone to a folder you have write permissions to it will work better? Like `Documents`.